# Error in android studio:App is crashing everytime

Tags: java, android

***Error***

> 12-15 23:11:33.843 28004-28004/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   12-15 23:11:34.004 28004-28004/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.kkkss.myprofileapp/com.example.kkkss.myprofileapp.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error
>   inflating class ImageView
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error
>   inflating class ImageView
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                          at com.example.kkkss.myprofileapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:10)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                       Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a
>   Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060063 a=-1
>   r=0x7f060063}
>                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2784)
>                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:126)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:681)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                          at com.example.kkkss.myprofileapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:10) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  12-15 23:11:43.173
>   28004-28004/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28004 SIG: 9

**Kotlin code**

```
package com.example.kkkss.myprofileapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/tony_stark_small"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="App"/>
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Tony Stark"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="24sp"
     android:textColor="#222222"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is `"@drawable/tony_stark_small"` present in your drawable folder?

Comment: yes it is present in drawable folder.